# Perl: show used subroutines

Tags: perl, optimization, subroutine, mason

In some project ( Mason ) there is a lot of perl modules (> 200). Really used only 5-10% from this code.
How i can look, which subroutines is used (or unused)?

Comment: Does this help you? http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2012/07/finding-unused-subroutines-but-with-ppi.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to choroba's link, you can use a profiler to show what subroutines are called (how many times and how long they took):

- [Profiling Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/2004/06/25/profiling.html)
- [Devel::NYTProf - Profiling Perl code](http://www.perl.org/about/whitepapers/perl-profiling.html)

Answer (score 4):

Consider to start using `Perl::Critic` from the command line:

```
perlcritic --single-policy=UnusedPrivateSubroutines --verbose 2 ./*.pl
```

You will get a list of the unused subroutines. To list unused variables:

```
perlcritic --single-policy=UnusedVariables --verbose 2 /root/*.pl
```

To audit your whole "mason" project for unused subroutines, something like

```
cat *.pl > all-perl-files.pl
```

and using again `percritic` on the `all-perl-files.pl` *may* give you an initial list. That's because if the same subroutine's name is declared in more than one file and got used somewhere in your project, it may get masked out of your unused list.